# Capabilities and mapping required for a role to be able to edit other's posts of a custom type, BUT only be able to edit their own blog posts

Tags: custom-post-types, capabilities, user-roles

I’m wondering if anyone can shed some like on an issue I'm having with custom post type capabilities.

My custom post type is Subject.
My custom role is Subject Editor

A Subject Editor has all the required custom capabilities to edit Subjects (eg. `edit_subjects`, `edit_others_subjects`). They can also edit Subjects created by others users. This is all working fine.

If also give Subject Editors the core `edit_posts` capability, so they can edit their blog posts too, then role can no longer edit (or see) Subjects created by other users.

It seems I have to also give Subject Editors the core `edit_others_posts` capability for the role to be able to edit the Subjects created by other users.

Unfortunately this last condition is undesirable in my instance. My Subject Editors should not be able to edit other's blog posts.

Does anyone know of a solution to this issue? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this plugin was the cause of the issue:

View Own Media Posts Only

https://wordpress.org/plugins/view-own-posts-media-only/

One disabled, custom capabilities worked as you would expect them to.